# Interrogative determiners: Usage of which and what? and in which context?

Tags: determiners, interrogatives

I'm reading and understand the idea of determiners. So as per my understanding, we use "which" as a determiner to ask a question about a specific group of people or things

When we are asking a general question we use "what" as a determiner.

So, my question is

1. **What** films do you like?
2. **Which** film did you watch?

In both the sentences I'm asking question only to one person. Correct me if I'm wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 1, the answer could be any film, whereas in 2, you expect an answer that selects one film from a restricted set - for example, you know what was showing in the cinema last night, and you're asking **which of those films** they went to see. You could also ask, 'what film did you watch?' if you don't know what their options were and expect any answer.

The number of people you're addressing is irrelevant here. The situation in which you're asking a question 'about a specific group of people' would be something like: 'which teacher takes your class?' You're asking the question **about** teachers (and you know all the teachers in the school, so you expect the answer to be one of them).

Note, though, that in the real world this what/which distinction is very often relaxed. You might especially come across 'what' used where 'which' might be more appropriate. It's not a hard and fast rule in casual speech.

Comment: @Igid- it means "What" is used to ask a question when there are an unknown or infinite number of answer.

Comment: So in this context - What colour of shoes do you wear with this dress AND Which colour of shoes do you wear with this dress. Later one is correct?